# K&R first edition, exercise 1.18 (test in the for statement is ungainly)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I could not had any conclusion about what the "test in loop statement" means in terms of programming. Is it about the tests in loop brackets or in curly brackets which are iterated by the loop ?

Exercise 1.18 is here:

```
char line[];
int max; 

main() 
{
    int len;
    extern int max;
    extern char save[];

    max = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)))
    if (len > max){
        max = len;
        copy();
    }
    if (max > 0)  printf("%s",save);
}

getline() 
{
    int c,i;
    extern char line[];

    for (i=0; i<= MAXLİNE -1 && ((c = getchar())!= EOF) && c != '\n';) 
        line[i++]=c;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        line[i] = c; 
        ++i;
    } 
    s[i] = '\0';
    return (i) ;
}

copy()   
{                          
    int i;
    extern char save[];
    extern char line[];

    int i = 0;
    while( (save[i] = line[i] ) != '\0') 
        ++i;
}
```

> Exercise l-18. The test in the for statement of getline above is rather
>   ungainly. Rewrite the program to make it clearer, but retain the same
>   behavior at end of file or buffer overflow. Is this behavior the most reasonable?

Comment: Please, get a newer book. Ungainly means "awkward". It is.

Comment: Did you lookup what the word "gainly" means? "awkward; clumsy" its saying the for loop `for (i=0; i<= MAXLİNE -1 && ((c = getchar())!= EOF) && c != '\n';)` is very hard/awkward to read and to make it more readable

Comment: The curly brackets aren't part of the `for` loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, not about vocabulary.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It is a reasonable and good question for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for your attentions! (Vlad and Scott)

Answer (score 1):

As it follows from the comments it seems the for loop should be rewritten to make the code more readable.

I can suggest the following solution substituting the for loop for a while loop.

```
getline() 
{
    int c, i;
    extern char line[];

    i = 0;

    while ( i <= MAXLINE -1 && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n' )
    { 
        line[i++] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        line[i++] = c; 
    } 

    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

After rewriting the function I see a bug. The variable `c` must be initialized and the first sub-condition in the while loop also must be changed.

So the function can look for example like

```
getline() 
{
    int c, i;
    extern char line[];

    i = 0;
    c = EOF;

    while ( i < MAXLINE - 1 && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n' )
    { 
        line[i++] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        line[i++] = c; 
    } 

    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 10

char line[MAXLINE];

int getline( void )
{
    int c, i;
    extern char line[];

    i = 0;
    c = EOF;

    while (i < MAXLINE - 1 && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n')
    {
        line[i++] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        line[i++] = c;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int main( void )
{
    int max = 0;
    int len;
    char save[MAXLINE];

    while ((len = getline()))
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            strcpy( save, line );
        }
    if (max > 0)  printf("%s", save);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output (if to run as a console application in Windows) might look like

```
1
123456789
12345
123
1234567
^Z
123456789
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I compiled the original code in the book then typed same lines as an input but program did not printed any line as an answer (I use TDM - GCC 5.01 compiler suite).

Comment: @OğuzKaanBULUT Your code contains many typos. For example what is s in this statement in the function s[i] = '\0';? Is not it line, is it? The function declaration does not have parameters, However you call it like while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE))).Also MAXLINE and MAXLİNE as it is written in your code contains a different symbol.

Comment: Yes, it was. I found also other typos and fixed them after posting here (initialized arrays with MAXLINE) but didn't work again.

Comment: I restarted the machine then now it works...C seems so strange..

Comment: @OğuzKaanBULUT  See my updated post.

Comment: Your update is more well suited for a beginner, it does not force reader of the book to allocate his focus to copy function and extern calls. Thank you.

Comment: Can i ask 'off-topic' holders to remove their holds? It seems  no another question topic exists about this solution in entire site.